# Как передать значение select в php Mailer?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Обратная связь на сайте реализована с помощью библиотеки `php mailer`. Возникла необходимость передачи выбранного значения тега `select`. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать.

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  class="services-form"> 
   <select class="select-input  input-form-items"> 
      <option value="">Степень загрязнения</option>
      <option value="1">Слабое</option>
      <option value="2">Среднее</option>
      <option value="3">Сильное</option>
   </select>
 </form>
```

```
<?php 

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$square = $_POST['square'];
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$email = $_POST['user_email'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';                                                                                           // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = ''; // Ваш логин от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->Password = ''; // Ваш пароль от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to / этот порт может отличаться у других провайдеров

$mail->setFrom(''); // от кого будет уходить письмо?
$mail->addAddress('');     // Кому будет уходить письмо 
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
// Прикрепление файлов
$mail->addAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с тестового сайта';
$mail->Body    = '' .$name . ' оставил заявку, его телефон ' .$phone. '<br>Почта этого пользователя: ' .$email. 'Площадь помещения:' .$adress. 'Площадь помещения' .$square;
$mail->AltBody = '';
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
}
?>
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  let form = $("#services-form-12");
  $(form).submit(function (e) {
  if (!form.get(0).checkValidity()) {
      form.get(0).reportValidity();
    }
  else {            
       sendForm(this);
      $(form).trigger('reset');
       return false;     
      function sendForm(form) {
        var fd = new FormData(document.querySelector("#services-form-12"));
        fd.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");
        $.ajax({
          url: "mail.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: fd,
          processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
          contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
        });
      }    
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: А что не получается? Опишите по подробнее.

Comment: как Вы передаете данные на сервер ?

Comment: Данные передаются с помощью ajax.

Comment: Не получается передать выбранное значение с помощью атрибута name и переменной в файле mail.php, как с номером телефона, например. Видимо нужен другой способ, а какой не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    $.get("/index.php?var="+valueSelected);
});
```

Comment: А если мне нужно передавать данные  при отправке формы с помощью ajax, то как быть?Прикрепил ещё скрипт с JS кодом

Comment: @PavelBogdanov `var selected = $( "#myselect option:selected" ).val();`

Comment: Хорошо, это понял. А как переданное значение через mail.php обработать?

Comment: @PavelBogdanov Не совсем вас понял. Вы получаете выбранный элемент, передаете его `url: "mail.php?selected="+selected ` а в mail.php уже работает с `$_GET['selected']`